# How to escape newline in the commandline?

Tags: linux, echo

I need to do this:

```
$ echo '
File
Contents
' > my-file
```

The problem is that the resulting file contains a newline at the beginning and at the end.

I tried this but didn't work:

```
$ echo '\
File
Contents\
' > my-file
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can use a HERE document?

```
cat << '==end' > my-file
File
Contents
==end
```

Comment: Yes this looks good. But how to send the result to a file? Right now it's only printing it on the screen.

Comment: @ChocoDeveloper: Use redirection. Answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

Another simple answer not mentioned is:

```
echo -e "Line 1\nLine 2"
```

The `-e` option causes `echo` to interpret backslash escape sequences.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n" "Line 1", "Line 2", "Line 3"
```

Comment: I need to be able to paste the file contents without any change, I can't separate it into lines. And I need to be able to execute this as a command, I don't want to open vim and paste it manually.

Comment: I think I cannot understand what you want to do. Do you want to just copy some files to another one?

Comment: I want to copy/paste file contents (ie: something I don't want to write by hand each time, like a config file) into a command to create the file, to automate an installation.

Comment: Then, a good example, is to use grep. For example, you find the line you want and then, count the lines you want to copy: `grep myline -A6` will copy from "myline" and the next 6 lines.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `cat` instead:

```
cat > file
```

Paste what you want to go into `file` and finish with <kbd>Ctrl+d</kbd> on an empty line.

Comment: But I want to do everything in a single command. If I can paste to a file, I could as well just have pasted into the file I need.

Comment: @ChocoDeveloper: ok, you're probably looking for the heredoc option then, see choroba's answer but with `> file` after the first `==end`.